# How to set UICues in a WinForms user control

Tags: winforms, user-controls, focus

I would like my user control to show a focus rectangle, but  `ShowFocusCues` is read-only. So far, from reading the docs, I understand that this will involve setting UICues with a bitwise enumeration,  but how and where do you tell the control to show a focus rectangle?

The UC repeats in a table layout and I'd like to clearly identify which repeating group has been entered (i.e. one of its controls has focus).

```
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
 ====================================================
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
 ====================================================
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
 title .................................
 start date ...........   expiry date...............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found the answer.

In the Enter and Leave events of the user control, BorderStyle can be set.